# Taking out levelling and classes - Replacements

Tags: feats, skills, game-design

So, my RPG isn't going to use levels or classes to determine advancement. I'm trying to keep it open as possible, and also I realize that if a character levels up, and then they fight slightly tougher monsters, then it's the same difficulty level and they might as well not level up at all.
Instead, I'm trying a feat/skill type system (like in Savage Worlds) where characters get Skills by spending Skill Points( which they get from doing important things - I'm trying to eliminate grinding as well). These skills won't increase their primary stats, but instead, give them things to do in the tactics department and fill out the character's portfolio. There are certain specialization areas, but it doesn't hold lots of characters back.
Because of the anti-leveling, most characters will have like 10 hitpoints, and so I've decreased damage rolls from d1(just a 1) to d6, instead of d4-d12 like in most systems. Characters won't have a barrel of hitpoints for monsters to stab holes in.
Thoughts? Ideas? Problems?

Comment: This question seems to have a bunch of questions it is asking at once and seems really broad to me. StackExchange works only when you have a single question that can have answers rated; right now you could have many answers that are all equally viable. I would try splitting the question up into multiple questions; one for each problem that you have encountered with your new system that you can't find a solution for.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.